# i get a Type error for __init__ saying it has no arguments when it clearly does. why is this? 'TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments'

Tags: python, kivy

this is all of my code. when i run, it works fine but when i press the button on the top right of the window, it crashes and gives a type error. i have reviewed it and cant find any problems. also ,a less major problem, but the button doesn't show the icon i have assigned to it but shows a white rectangle. i have deleted some classes and commands. this still gives the same error message.

```
 from os.path import join, exists
    import json
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, SlideTransition
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.properties import ListProperty,StringProperty,NumericProperty,BooleanProperty,AliasProperty
    
    class NoteView(Screen):
        note_index : NumericProperty()
        note_title : StringProperty()
        note_content : StringProperty()
    
    class NoteListItem(BoxLayout):
        note_index : NumericProperty()
        note_title : StringProperty()
        note_content : StringProperty()
    
    class Notes(Screen):
        data = ListProperty()
        def _get_data_for_widget(self):
            return[{
                'note_index': index,
                'note_content': item['content'],
                'note_title': item['title']}
                for index, item in enumerate(self.data)]
    
        data_for_widgets =  AliasProperty(_get_data_for_widget,bind= ['data'])
    
    class MutableTextInput(FloatLayout):
    
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super(MutableTextInput,self).__init__(**kwargs)
            Clock.schedule_once(self.prepare,0)
    
    class MainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.notes = Notes(name ='Notes')
            self.load_notes()
            self.transition=  SlideTransition(duration =.3)
            root =  ScreenManager(transition =  self.transition)
            root.add_widget(self.notes)
            return root
    
        def load_notes(self):
            if not exists(self.notes_fn):
                return
            with open(self.note_fn,'w') as fd:
                data = json.load(fd)
            self.notes.data = data
    
        def edit_note(self,note_index):
            note  = self.notes.data[note_index]
            name  = 'note{}'.format(note_index)
    
            if self.root.has_screen(name):
                self.root.remove_widget(self.root.get_screen(name))
    
            view = NoteView(
                name =  name,
                note_index = note_index,
                note_title =  note.get('title'),
                note_content = note.get('Content'))
            self.root.add_widget(view)
            self.transition.direction  ='left'
            self.root.current =  view.name
    
        def add_note(self):
            self.notes.data.append({'title': 'New note' , 'Content': ''})
            note_index =  len(self.notes.data)-1
            self.edit_note(note_index)
    
        @property
        def notes_fn(self):
            return join(self.user_data_dir,'notes.json')
    
    MainApp().run()
    
    Error message
    
        [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\sammi\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-07-08_10.txt
        [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18
        [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.10
        [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
        [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
        [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
        [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
        [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
        [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
        [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
        [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 30.0.101.1338'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 30.0.101.1338'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
        [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
        [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
         Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1503, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1505, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 31, in _get_data_for_widget
             for index, item in enumerate(self.data)]
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
             for index, item in enumerate(self.data)]
         KeyError: 'content'
         Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.observable_list_dispatch'
         Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1503, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
           File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1505, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 31, in _get_data_for_widget
             for index, item in enumerate(self.data)]
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
             for index, item in enumerate(self.data)]
         KeyError: ('content',)
        [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
         Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 147, in <module>
             MainApp().run()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
             runTouchApp()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
             EventLoop.window.mainloop()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
             self._mainloop()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
             EventLoop.idle()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
             self.dispatch_input()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
             post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
             wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
             self.dispatch('on_release')
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
             exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.kv", line 122, in <module>
             on_release : app.add_note()
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 127, in add_note
             self.edit_note(note_index)
           File "C:\Users\sammi\OneDrive\Documents\python GUI projects\Notely\main.py", line 119, in edit_note
             note_content = note.get('content'))
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 265, in __init__
             super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
             super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
             super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           File "C:\Users\sammi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
             super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
         TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments
        [Finished in 2.256s]
```

Comment: I don't see the line `note_content = note.get('content'))` in `edit_note`. Are you sure this code is exactly what you ran when you got that error?

Comment: yes this is the same but I don't have that line in the code

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to remove parts of the UI, class setup etc. that aren't relevant to the error; try to give us the *shortest code possible* that we can still read clearly, copy and paste and run, and see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: should i create a whole new question or just post it here?

Comment: Just edit the question

Comment: Try replacing `:` in your attr. definitions with `=`.

Comment: It appears that you are using the dict key `content` in some places and `Content` in others. Those are different keys.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. Apart from the issues mentioned above, your `kvlang` contains various wrong things like lowercase class name, widget within canvas, undefined class etc. to name a few. First try fixing those issues.